# change position of draggable element with mouse dragging and releasing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have made a drag and droppable element. I want to change the position of the element by grabbing it and dragging it inside a div that allows the drop. Here is the code to drag and drop:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img class="poto" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Here is the position change code in jquery

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
                grid: [2, 2]
            });

        });
    </script>
    
    
     <img  class="draggable ui-widget-content" class="poto" src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
```

**But when I use both as the same code this does not work.**

please solve this problem I'll be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.ui.js library for the same this make your code very simple
[jquery-ui library](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js)

please refer docs
[jquery-ui docs](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: can you give any solution with the code that I provided because I want to add the code inside the div where I dropped the element with that library I cannot do so

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).